# Select specific character within text that matched regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the characters `<` and `>` from the text.
I have a regex as below:

```
(<span[^>]+class\s*=\s*("|')subValue\2[^>]*>)[^<]*(<\/span>)|(<br(\/*)>)
```

It is to target `<br/>`, `<br>`, `<span class="subValue">......</span>`. And I want to replace the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

When I wrapped it with a big bracket, it doesn't select out the `<` and `>` that from the `<span>` or `<br>`. Instead, it selected all `<` and `>`.

```
(<|>)(?!(<span[^>]+class\s*=\s*("|')subValue\2[^>]*>)[^<]*(<\/span>)|(<br(\/*)>))
```

What is wrong with the regex?

I have created a [sample here](https://regex101.com/r/nW5zN5/1).

Code snippet sample.

```js
var str = '-<br><span class="subValue">Value Here<br/>';
regex = new RegExp('(?<=span|br)(<|>)|(<|>)(?=span|br)|(?<="subValue"|\'subValue\')>|<(?=\/)|(?<=br\/)[\s]*>', 'gi');
//str = str.match(regex);
str = str.replace(regex, 'Testing');
$('#lol').html(str);
```

```html
<div id="result" style="border:1px solid red;"></div>
```

Comment: Hey look.. This is my favorite post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @choz, if can, I won't do this as well. Currently I'm getting a whole string of HTML returned from external service, and just been told that these HTML should be normal text, shouldn't be part of HTML. So I have no choice to use regex to do this.

Comment: Actually, I don't really get your question. The sample you provide seemed to match  all `<` and `>`. Yet you said that It doesn't select them in your question.

Comment: What I means is that it doesn't select out the `<` and `>` from the `<span>` and `<br>`, instead, it selected out all `<` and `>` from the overall input.

Comment: Will this do? `(?<=span|br)(<|>)|(<|>)(?=span|br)|(?<="|')>|<(?=\/)`

Comment: Yes, it does most of the work. Thank you for your fast response, and your favorite post.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? Please leave some comments as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just add this to the answer.

```
(?<=span|br)(<|>)|(<|>)(?=span|br)|(?<="|')>|<(?=\/)
```

This will match;

> - All `<` or `>` that happens after `span` or `br`
> - All `<` or `>` that happens before `span` or `br`
> - All `>` that happens after `'` or `"` (quote or double-quotes)
> - All `<` that happens before `/`

Comment: Oh look, even StackOverflow treats everything after `"` as a string.

Comment: Seems like need to convert your regex to be working for JavaScript, as lookbehinds not working in JavaScript.

Comment: That's a javascript regex, and I've tested it on the sample link you gave. In which case it doesn't work? Perhaps I can be some of help.

Comment: I have added the sample into my post. I'm getting `invalid regexp group` error, and I think it is from the `lookbehinds`.

Comment: My bad. I chosen the PHP tab in the regex101. Sorry.

Comment: @Chin Oh, I didn't realize that as well.. Yes, the lookbehinds aren't working in this answer. I will try to play with it again later and see if I can be of any help. You shouldn't mark this as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

> `(<|>)(?!(<span…` What is wrong with the regex?

You not just *wrapped it with a big bracket*, rather you put a pattern of `<|>` in front, followed by a negative lookahead which never matches, particularly because it looks for *another* `<`.

---

Here I used your original regex unchanged, doing the wanted replacements with a replace [*function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
text = '\
<span class="subValue"></span>\
<br>\
<br>\
<span class=\'subValue\'>dsa</span>\
<>';
regex = /(<span[^>]+class\s*=\s*("|')subValue\2[^>]*>)[^<]*(<\/span>)|(<br(\/*)>)/g;
function replacer(match) { return match.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); }
text = text.replace(regex, replacer);
// display the result
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
```